# Why does $u=e^{-i\omega x}e^{-k\omega^2t}$ "clearly" solve the 1-D heat equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, exponential-function

So one of my least favorite things that textbooks do is using the words "clearly", "it should be obvious", etc.

In my PDEs class, we've started the Fourier Transform, and I missed the first day of it so I am trying to read through my book. Regarding the heat equation on an infinite domain, it tells me this:

> From our previous experience, we note that the expression $\sin{\frac{n\pi x} L } e^{-k(\frac{n\pi} L)^2t}$ solves the heat equation [$u_t=k\cdot u_{xx}$] for integer $n$, as well as $\cos{\frac{n\pi x} L } e^{-k(\frac{n\pi} L)^2t}$. In fact, it is clear that 
>   $$u(x,t)=e^{-i\omega x}e^{-k\omega^2t}$$
>   solves [the heat equation as well], for arbitrary $\omega$ both positive and negative.

It's not "clear" to me why this happens, so I tried 'deriving' this form for a bit by using $\omega=\frac{n\pi}L$ and writing both of the trig functions in their exponential forms

$$\sin x = \frac 1 2(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$$
$$\cos x = \frac 1 2(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$$

(and with terms like $e^{i\omega x}$ as well) and added, multiplied, etc, but to no avail.

To be clear (no pun intended), I know that the $e^{-k\omega^2t}$ term is the same as the exponential term in both of the expressions which solve the equation, but I'm failing to see where $e^{-i\omega x}$ came into play.

Any advice as to how I can figure this out? (If possible, please give me some advice on 'deriving' it myself before giving a full answer?)

Comment: Just differentiate the given function, no need to write it in terms of trig functions or substitute constants! All you need is the product rule and $\partial_x e^{kx} = ke^{kx}$.

Comment: Use variable-seperable,all doubts will get cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$, then
$$ X(x)T'(t) = k X''(x)T(t)$$
$$ \frac{T'}{T} = k \frac{X''}{X}$$

Since the LHS is only in terms of $t$ and the RHS is only in terms of $x$, they have to both be equal to a constant, so we let
$$ \frac{X''}{X} = -\omega^2 $$
$$ \frac{T'}{T} = -k\omega^2 $$

Solving the above ODEs give $X(x) = e^{-i\omega x}$ and $T(t) = e^{-k\omega^2t}$

**Note:** You can also verify the solution by just taking the derivatives and see that
$$ u_t = -k\omega^2 e^{-i\omega x}e^{-k\omega^2t}$$
$$ u_{xx} = -\omega^2 e^{-i\omega x}e^{-k\omega^2t} $$

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I was overthinking it and not even considering the fact that the usual $-\lambda$ could be replaced by another constant.